# Check if entry exists in Firebase Realtime Databse (Python)

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to retrieve login information from my Realtime DB in Firebase.[image: img]

As an example, I want to detect whether the provided username already exists in the db.

Here is a code snippet I'm attemping to work with.

`ref.child("Users").order_by_child("Username").equal_to("Hello").get()`

It does not however work, and instead displays this message:

`firebase_admin.exceptions.InvalidArgumentError: Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "Username", for path "/Users", to the rules`

Is there something wrong with my code snippet or should I use a different alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggests, you need to add `".indexOn": "Username"` in your security rules as shown below:

```
{
  "rules": { 
    "Users": {
      ".indexOn": "Username",
      // ... rules
      "$uid": {
        // ... rules
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data#section-indexing-order-by-child) for more information.